# Create a validator in SmartGwt to check if String is an Integer

Tags: java, smartgwt

I have a `TextItem` and I want to set a `Validator` on it so it checks that the input is a integer ONLY.

```
TextItem textItem = new TextItem();
textItem.setValidator(myValidator)
```

How should I create my `myValidator` to check this? I have:

```
myValidatorcv = new CustomValidator() {

        @Override
        protected boolean condition(Object value) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(value);){
                return true;
            }else
                return false;
            }
        }
};
```

Is that the best way to do this? Also do I also need to catch the number format exception inside the validator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that the best way to do this?

Probably. Any time you can leverage the built-in capability of the framework, that's usually an indicator of a good solution.
There are some that might say that exception driven programming isn't the best approach because of the cost to handle them, but that's up to you.

> Also do I also need to catch the number format exception inside the validator?

Yes, that's how you will know if it fails or not.

```
myValidatorcv = new CustomValidator() {

        @Override
        protected boolean condition(Object value) {
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
                return true;
            } catch (NumberFormatException) {
                return false;
            }
        }
};
```

I'm not totally familiar with this framework, but if you can utilize generics to ensure that the object you are validating is an `Integer` or `String` rather than an `Object`, that would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the IntegerRangeValidator.

https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/validator/IntegerRangeValidator.html